# Как правильно выйти из цикла?

Tags: python, while, mouse-event, event-loop

В коде ниже выход происходит только в начале петли (при условии **pressed "esc"**). Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно прервать петлю в процессе проигрывания событий и не дожидаться завершения полного цикла, т.е. до **time.sleep(5)**?

```
import mouse
import keyboard
import time

#This is the list where all the events will be stored
events = []
#Waiting for 'ctrl' to be pressed
keyboard.wait("ctrl")
print('record')
#starting the recording
mouse.hook(events.append)
#Waiting for 'ctrl' to be pressed
keyboard.wait("ctrl")
print('playback...')
#Stopping the recording
mouse.unhook(events.append)

while True:
    #sec sleep
    time.sleep(5)
    mouse.play(events)
    #press to fin the script
    if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
        print('bye')
        break
```

Для следующих вариантов результат тот же:

```
    while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
        mouse.play(events)
    print('bye')
    break
```

и

```
while True:
if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
    print('bye')
    break
mouse.play(events)
```

Comment: Перенесите is_pressed в начало, а sleep в конец.

Comment: Да по-разному уже крутил, не заметил разницы... воспроизведение действий **mouse.play(events)** не удаётся прервать через "esc" в процессе выполнения events. "esc" прерывает цикл только после полного воспроизведения **mouse.play(events)**, т.е. "esc" нужно нажать в промежуток между двумя итерациями цикла. Если **if keyboard.is_pressed("esc")** использовать во время воспроизведения events, цикл не завершится...
Пробовал, в том числе следующим образом:

`while True:<br/>
    if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
    mouse.play(events)
        print('bye')
        break`

Comment: Пример в первом сообщении темы.

Answer (score 0):

Исходный код [mouse.play](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse/blob/master/mouse/__init__.py#L257-L280) - простой цикл.

Скопируйте метод к себе, вставьте в цикл проверку не нажал ли пользователь Esc. Да, придётся разрешить зависимости вроде `_os_mouse` и `_time`, но это не сложно.